# Why do I get a "30km/h speed has been exceeded" dashboard message?

Tags: vw, troubleshooting, golf, warning-sound

I have a Golf VI (2009), which in the last few days started to give me the message:

```
30km/h speed has been exceeded
```

I have no idea why it happens. I checked:

- the speed limit for winter tires: disabled.
- the cruise control: disabled.

Turning the car off and on again, wouldn't work.

The vehicle manual makes reference to this limit only when it talks about the parking sensors. In fact my wife, who noticed the problem a couple of hours before I did, said that in this one instance, the sensors started to beep like the car was very near to something, even if there was no obstacle.

Funny thing, though, because the sensors work.
I tried to switch off the sensors, then again on. The message is always there.

What can be the cause of this problem (which is also the source of an annoying beep everytime I exceed 30km/h)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most VW/Audi/Seat cars have a setting for a speed warning, every time you exceed it you get a bleep. It's annoying, but you can turn it off, or simply set it to something high where a warning makes sense. The directions are different for many models, your manual should tell you how your particular one works. There's also [this forum's](http://www.vwaudiforum.co.uk/forum/showthread.php/87417-Setting-speed-warning/page1) thread which has many options.

Comment: Yep, speed warning only makes sense at 80mph for me, lol.

Comment: Glad we could help @Noldor130884!